# Sort List by Integer

Tags: java, android

I get the Latitude and Longtitude from my Database and I calculate the distance between two persons in the RecyclerView Adapter.

I want to sort these items by distance, but I have no clue how I can do this.

My Adapter:

```
public class HomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeAdapter.ViewHolder>{

Context context;
List<HomeGetter> homeGetters;
HomeCallback homeCallback;

public HomeAdapter(Context context, List<HomeGetter> homeGetters, HomeCallback homeCallback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.homeGetters = homeGetters;
    this.homeCallback = homeCallback;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_home_profil,parent,false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    calculate_age calculate_age = new calculate_age();
    final HomeGetter homeGetter = homeGetters.get(position);



        String[] splittedAge = homeGetter.getBirthday().split("\\.");
        try {
            String age = calculate_age.getAge(context,Integer.valueOf(splittedAge[0]),Integer.valueOf(splittedAge[1]),Integer.valueOf(splittedAge[2]));
            String username = homeGetter.getUsername().substring(0,1).toUpperCase() + homeGetter.getUsername().substring(1);
            holder.textViewUsername.setText(username + "," + age);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    Picasso.with(context).load(homeGetter.getImageURL()).resize(600,700).centerCrop().into(holder.imageView);

    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            homeCallback.getPosition(position);
        }
    });

    holder.textViewLocation.setText(homeGetter.getLocation());

    if(homeGetter.getStatus().equals("0")){
        holder.status.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.offline));
    }else {
        holder.status.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.online));
    }



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return homeGetters.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;
    TextView textViewUsername;
    CardView cardView;
    TextView textViewLocation;
    ImageView status;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewThumb);
        textViewUsername = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProfilUsername);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewProfil);
        textViewLocation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewLocation);
        status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewOnlinestatus);
    }

}
}
```

On this line I get the distance in km:

```
holder.textViewLocation.setText(homeGetter.getLocation());
```

e.g 544

Is it possible to sort the list in the adapter? 
Or how can I sort this?
So, how can I achive this?

---

The Activity

```
pullData.getData(USERNAME, "1", new Pullcallback() {
        @Override
        public void getSingleData(String data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void getMultipleData(String[] multipledatas) {
            GENDER = multipledatas[5];
            GENDERSEARCH = multipledatas[6];

            GetStrangers getStrangers = new GetStrangers(Home.this);
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put("USERNAME",USERNAME);
            map.put("GENDER",GENDER);
            map.put("SEARCH",GENDERSEARCH);
            getStrangers.strangers(map, "7", new Pullcallback() {
                @Override
                public void getSingleData(String data) {

                }

                @Override
                public void getMultipleData(final String[] multipledatas) {

                    // username,imagelink,position,birthday
                    // imageURL,username,birthday,location

                    pullData.getData(USERNAME, "2", new Pullcallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void getSingleData(String data) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void getMultipleData(String[] multipledatas2) {

                            String[] split1 = multipledatas2[1].split(",");
                            String[] split2 = multipledatas[2].split(",");

                            float lat1 = Float.valueOf(split1[0]);
                            float lng1 = Float.valueOf(split1[1]);

                            float lat2 = Float.valueOf(split2[0]);
                            float lng2 = Float.valueOf(split2[1]);

                            Collections.sort(getterList, new Comparator<HomeGetter>() {
                                public int compare(HomeGetter s1, HomeGetter s2) {
                                    return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1.getLocation()), Integer.parseInt(s2.getLocation()));
                                }
                            });

                            homeGetter = new HomeGetter(multipledatas[1],multipledatas[0],multipledatas[3],String.valueOf(Math.round(Calculator.calculateDistance(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2))),multipledatas[4]);

                            getterList.add(homeGetter);

                            homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(String errormessage) {

                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String errormessage) {

                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String errormessage) {

        }
    });

    pullData.getData(USERNAME, "2", new Pullcallback() {
        @Override
        public void getSingleData(String data) {

        }

        @Override
        public void getMultipleData(String[] multipledatas) {

            if(multipledatas[7].equals("0")){

                Intent intentFirststep = new Intent(Home.this,Firststep.class);
                startActivity(intentFirststep);
                finish();
            }else {

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String errormessage) {

        }
    });


    recyclerViewHome = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewHome);
    homeAdapter = new HomeAdapter(Home.this, getterList, new HomeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void getPosition(int position) {
            Intent stranger = new Intent(Home.this,Stranger.class);
            stranger.putExtra("USERNAME",getterList.get(position).getUsername());
            startActivity(stranger);
            finish();
        }
    });
    recyclerViewHome.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerViewHome.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(Home.this,3));
    recyclerViewHome.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerViewHome.setAdapter(homeAdapter);

}
```

But it is not working correctly it shows me 4,14,507 and 12
but it shoild sort 4,12,14,507

Comment: you need to make the homeGetter implement comparable, then you can use `PriorityQueue` object, that way when insert object to the list they will be inserted with order or use `Collections.sort()` for sorting list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your activity where you are passing your `ArrayList` just do this before passing it.

```
Collections.sort(homeGetter, new Comparator<HomeGetter>() {
                public int compare(HomeGetter s1, HomeGetter s2) {
                    return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1.getLocation()), Integer.parseInt(s2.getLocation()));
                }
            });
```

P.S. Don't use parse if you are already storing as integers.
Happy to help.

EDIT:
Put it here-

```
getterList.add(homeGetter);

Collections.sort(homeGetter, new Comparator<HomeGetter>() {
            public int compare(HomeGetter s1, HomeGetter s2) {
                return Integer.compare(Integer.parseInt(s1.getLocation()), Integer.parseInt(s2.getLocation()));
            }
        });

homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It is not working correctly. I will add the activity

Comment: Please try debugging your code with breakpoints and log-cat, and come with a specific problem so that I can assist you further.

Comment: I have added the activity

Comment: See my edited answer, put the sort code just before homeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, please tell if this helped. Let's make your code work :)

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to help, please upvote and accept the answer so that it would also help others :)

Comment: Accepted but can't upvode ... need reputation haha

Answer (score 1):

You can also sort the `List<HomeGetter> homegetters` using a Comparator & then initialize `HomeAdapter` with sorted homegetters list.

An Example:

`homegetters.sort((hG1, hG2) -> hG1.getLocation().compareTo(hG2.getLocation()));`

Above line will sort homegetters list based on `getLocation()`.

**Edit:**

In your activity, you are sorting the List first and then adding an item into it. 
You should instead add all the items first & then sort the List.